# Twig Rendering - Excessively Slow on one installation

Tags: php, twig

not so sure my question has its place on StackOverflow. So sorry if it's not.

I have an issue with some Twig Rendering in a Symfony project.

Basically, I have the projects installed on 2 different servers, on the first server with Twig 2.4.4 and PHP 7.1.13, the rendering takes around 500ms (which is acceptable in our case).

But on the second server (which by the way has better specs), with Twig 2.4.8 and PHP 7.2.5, the same page (and exactly the same data) takes around 2500ms to render (which is let's say it, too slow.)

The times I provided is only for the rendering part of the page and not the full code execution (which is always slower on the second server but not by much, usually by 30ms by "part", so I already removed other factors like DB connexion and all )

I was thinking that it might be related to some PHP modules not being enabled on the second server but there is not much difference.

Do any of you have any idea of what I should investigate next?

Is there any tool that could help me look around which part is taking the most time to render inside Twig?

Comment: Have you checked whether Twig caches its templates on the second server?

Comment: Yes, it does cache it too...

Comment: I have a similiar issue. Cache enabled, on WIN a server it takes 8s to render a page (just the render command). Same project, same config, takes <1s on LINUX server.